# Can't load view from an external xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

The project i'm using is the sample code named ["Tabster"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tabster/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011213) provided by Apple.

I can load a view from a external xib by this:

1. In MainWindow.xib, drag a view controller to the tab bar controller.
2. File -> New -> File, add a new class named "NewTabItemA", subclass of UIViewController, with "With XIB for User Interface." selected.
3. In MainWindow.xib, change the Class of the new view controller to "NewTabItemA" in Identity Inspector and change the NIB Name to "NewTabItemA" in Attributes Inspector.

I can **NOT** load a view from a external xib while only the second step is different.

1. In MainWindow.xib, drag a view controller to the tab bar controller.
2. File -> New -> File, add a new class named "NewTabItemB", subclass of UIViewController, leave "With XIB for User Interface." unselected.
3. File -> New -> File, add a new xib file from the "View" template, name it as "NewTabItemB".
4. In NewTabItemB.xib, change the file owner to "NewTabItemB".
5. Control drag the file owner to the View, set it as the file owner's outlet.
6. In MainWindow.xib, change the Class of the new view controller to "NewTabItemB" in Identity Inspector and change the NIB Name to "NewTabItemB" in Attributes Inspector.

What did i miss?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change identifier of the xib? In interface builder click on window and set it in the properties. (3d tab)